# Locking versions of node module transitive dependencies (dependencies of dependencies)

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm needing some help locking versions of node module transitive dependencies (dependencies of dependencies).

My company uses a mirror of npmjs.com registry. In light of recent malicious `npm` packages this mirror has enabled a feature to "quarantine" newly published packages for n-number of days until they have been deemed safe to use. When a newly published package is quarantined in our mirror it is not available for use and will `403` when trying to install.

We've since started to use strong versions of our packages in our `package.json` file - no range qualifiers are found in our `package.json` - no `*`'s - no `~`'s - no `^`'s.

We use `yarn` as our package manager. We commit our `yarn.lock` files to git. Upon looking more closely at our `yarn.lock` file, we obviously see transitive dependencies using range qualifiers. Transitive dependencies using range qualifiers in combination with our `npm` mirror's quarantine rules for newly published packages is causing a new `yarn install` error almost daily.

We're looking for a way to lock down specific versions of our transitive dependencies.

Do we manually update our `yarn.lock` file removing all range qualifiers? Do we switch to a different package manager? `npm`? `pnpm`?

Thoughts?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think this is what you get with `npm ci`. As for yarn, have you tried with `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`. Not an expert on the topic, but according to the documentation, it looks promising :)

Answer (score 4):

Hey in yarn you can specify in the package.json resolutions

```
"resolutions": {
    "d2/left-pad": "1.1.1",
    "c/**/left-pad": "^1.1.2"
}
```

You can read more [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)